# browser autocomplete attribute in HTML form not working

Tags: jquery, html, forms

we have used jquery autocomplete for an input box so that user is given suggestions as he types along.

the issue we are facing is that most of the time the jQuery's suggestion list is hidden behind the browser's suggestion list . and if we press Escape, the jquery suggestion list probably also disappears.

have tried to use `autocomplete="off"` but doesn't seem to have any affect at least in Chrome

personally do not want to complicate the matter by using session keys to make the name unique like suggested in the following post

[How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

the complete tag is as under:

`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="EmployeeName" value="@Model.EmployeeName" autocomplete="off" />`

any help appreciated.

Comment: have you checked `autocomplete` in DOM?

Comment: yes.. its rendering

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava personally do not want to complicate things . hoping that it can be resolved with ease through HTML5 :)

Comment: What part of the suggested question is not HTML5?

Comment: they suggest appending unique session key with the name and saving that in server side. and when data is posted, simply strip that key from name to get the actual key/value

Comment: Are you using a any plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently had to debug this too we found that `autocomplete="new-password"` did the trick as a completely random workaround

```html
<input type="text" autocomplete="new-password" />
```

now you've provided more information from the comments see
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js

take note of the line that says

```
this.element.attr( "autocomplete", "off" );
```

needs to change to

```
this.element.attr( "autocomplete", "new-password" );
```

looks like the plugin hasn't been updated for handling this chrome bug. You could update the jquery-ui plugin directly, override it in a custom script, choose a different plugin.

Comment: same issue in this case well.. when given `autocomplete="new-password"` , the browser still renders `autocomplete="off"`. Have even tried to clear cache

Comment: thats strange, is some javascript interfering with it? browser shouldn't be changing this value have to tested with turning javascript off? It must be an issue with the jquery plugin, it might be forcing the value.

Comment: we are using jquery autocomplete plugin on the tag 
that is why the normal autocomplete needs to be hidden so that the user can see the suggestions received from the server

Comment: which one mate theres lots of jquery autocomplete plugins, can you post the url and check the plugin to see if it is forcing autocomplete off